# How to convert focus image to out of focus in Photoshop?

Tags: photo-editing

I'm looking for an editing skill that let me be built out of a fouse image from focus image. By out focus, I mean totally out of focus not only blurry background. In reality, we can achieve this image  by changing  the manual focus, which gives us an unclear image from all elements in the view

the following examples might help:
https://www.deviantart.com/stephanepellennec/art/The-Door-522701745

https://www.artlimited.net/16747/art/photography-when-it-never-comes-digital-people-miscellaneous-male/en/433795

Comment: it won't be the same thing, but the simplest way might be adding gaussian blur.

Comment: thank you @FábioDias. Yeah it's my last chance  but I hope I can find a more decent way to do that

Comment: Hi @Hueco, I have edited my post by providing an example. thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking specifically to recreate the blurred silhouettes in those examples?

Comment: @mattdm Yes, that my goal. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Try morphological operators. An opening should get a more similar result, alternate with closings (with increasing size) to smooth more stuff around it. Maybe using different structuring elements to give it noise.

Comment: These look like a "median blur" filter.

Answer (score 2):

This is my subpar attempt of trying to replicate this effect:

Image that I'm trying to replicate:

[image]
[image]

Settings for Lens Blur (ignore preview image):
[image]

Settings for noise:

[image]

I then added a photo filter layer with color #dcd6c6 and luminosity of 88%, unchecked preserve luminosity. I then pained over the beach with a bit of the warm grey and blurred it.

Then, to add the bokeh, I duplicated the original image and used these settings for Lens Blur:

[image]

Massagged in the bokeh by adjusting the darkness levels and setting the mode to overlay:

[image]

Final image:

[image]